# What's a proper way to install Ruby <1.9.3 on OS X Lion with Xcode 4.3?

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, xcode4.3

Until recently I used to have `Xcode 4.2` with the `osx-gcc-installer` installed on top of it, which worked quite well for older versions of Ruby.

The thing is, that now that I installed `Xcode 4.3` with the command line tools (for homebrew), I found that I don't have `gcc-4.2` on my system.

From what I was able to find, **the usual way to install pre 1.9.3 is to either get an older version of Xcode, or using the osx-gcc-installer**. I also found a warning saying that if I install osx-gcc-installer over Xcode 4.3, it will cause problems with node.js.

As I'm currently doing both iOS and node.js development alongside Ruby, I can't really do any of these things. Which means I can only work with 1.9.3, which is the only Ruby version that can be compiled with LLVM.

**Is there a clean way to install any older version of Ruby without sacrificing Xcode 4.3?** The solution that comes to my mind is having gcc-4.2 in some kind of non-system-wide sandbox and specify it's path when installing Ruby, but I'm not really sure how to do this properly.

Comment: What version of Ruby would you like to use instead? 1.9.3 is the best 1.9 and it's about time 1.8 finally disappeared...

Comment: @ShaunHare RVM doesn't solve the problem, since it will use LLVM and fail when installing.

Comment: @MichaelKohl I've been having a lot of trouble wiht 1.9.3 crashing when running specs, that's why I have most of my applications running on 1.9.2. I also need 1.8.7 and REE for some legacy stuff.

Comment: Interesting, I used 1.9.3 on OSX since p0 and never had any trouble with it. I guess http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1397300529/railsapp will be a relief for a lot of people...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

See this link for the process required to get GCC-4.2 onto a machine with Xcode 4.3 without overwriting other components.

[Xcode 4.3, Homebrew, and Ruby](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/03/02/xcode-4-dot-3-homebrew-and-ruby/)

It will obviate the need for the instructions below:

RVM should work if you  set the default compiler for RVM to gcc. Place this in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

RVM should then use GCC to compile.

If you don't want to have `CC` set permanently then you could try installing with:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.8.7
```

Comment: This works only if I install osx-gcc-installer (gcc-4.2) over the Xcode install ... which breaks other things, like node.js, which depend on clean Xcode install.

Comment: Updated answer with potential solution.

Comment: perfect, the article is exactly what I needed.